# Getting 'cannot read property 'offsetwidth' of undefined bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I get the `offsetwidth` undefined in spite of adding active class and also defining my jquery just above my js function. I have to use carousel for my work and I tried a mock one for practice. My first active image is displaying and after I click next I get this error in console and the images are not sliding.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <title>mycooking</title>

</head>
<body>
  <!--indicatiors-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!--wrapper for slides-->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item-active">
            <img class="first-slide" src="/img/dosa.jpg" alt="dosa" />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img class="second-slide" src="/img/idli.jpg" alt="idli" />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img class="third-slide" src="img/vada.jpg" alt="vada" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--Left and right controls-->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      $("#myCarousel").carousel({
          interval: 1200
      })
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is `offsetwidth` and not `offsetWidth`

Comment: Sorry it is 'offsetWidth' I am getting

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

Comment: <!--wrapper for slides-->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item-active">
            <img class="first-slide" src="/img/dosa.jpg" alt="dosa" />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img class="second-slide" src="/img/idli.jpg" alt="idli" />
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img class="third-slide" src="img/vada.jpg" alt="vada" />
          </div>
        </div>

Comment: <!--Left and right controls-->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      $("#myCarousel").carousel({
        interval: 1200
      })
    });
  </script>

Comment: Please put the code as part of the question instead of putting it in comments. Click the edit button on the lower left.

Comment: ^ Just edit your post and add the code. It's too hard to read like that

Comment: Please, *please* use the Edit button to edit the code into your question rather than posting it in comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this line in your HTML:

```
<div class="item-active">
```

to

```
<div class="item active">
```

That hyphen shouldn't be there. If you need an `item-active` class, add it after those two, like `<div class="item active item-active">`. `item` and `active` are classes bootstrap uses to run the carousel. Without them on that first slide, you'll get that error.

HTH,
-Ted