# cannot read property 'offsetwidth' of undefined bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented a bootstrap carousel with angular JS but i have noticed that sometimes I get an error "bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'offsetwidth' of undefined bootstrap carousel" and the slider stops working when I try to click the controls but sometimes it works perfectly fine.

Can someone help me with this

```
<div class="top" ng-show = "open_popup"  tabindex="-1" >
  <div id="myCarousel1" class="slider carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- <i class="fa fa-times closePopup" aria-hidden="true" ng- click = "closePopup();"></i> -->                   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">                        
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="image in carouselimages" ng-if="open_popup" ng-class="{active:$index == carouselImageActive}">
      <img ng-src="./uploads/{{image.imagename}}">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel1" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262999/getting-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-undefined-bootstrap